# Определить количество предков

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

Вот пример программы, определяющей всех предков у какого-либо потомка

```
father(andy,bob).
father(bob,carl).
father(carl,dan).
father(dan,elon).
father(elon,fred).
predecessor(X, Z) :- father(X, Z).
predecessor(X, Z) :- father(X, Y), predecessor( Y, Z).
```

Как подсчитать количество предков у потомка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать предикаты `findall/3` и `length/2`. Первый найдет все возможные решения и запишет их в список, второй посчитает количество элементов в списке:

```
predecessor_count(X, N) :- findall(Z, predecessor(Z,X), L),
                           length(L,N).
```

Однако такой подход может приводить к переполнению стека.

Более предпочтительным вариантом является использование предиката `aggregate/3`:

```
predecessor_count_1(X, N) :- aggregate(count, Z^predecessor(Z,X), N).
```

либо предиката `aggregate_all/3`:

```
predecessor_count_2(X, N) :- aggregate_all(count, predecessor(_,X), N).
```